# Where can I find all the changs between Python 2 and 3

Tags: python

Where can I find a list of changes between Python 2 and 3?

I am starting new projects in Python 3 and, I am fining a number of third party modules for Django seem to be written in Python 2. I don't have a problem updating them and committing the changes back, but I would like to know what to look out for before committing back, so I can do it properly.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: [What's new in Python 3.0?](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) You may also find the [2to3 tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) useful.

Comment: Googling `list of changes between Python 2 and 3` returns [this](http://inventwithpython.com/appendixa.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick overview of the difference between the two Python branches:

[Python2orPython3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

Keep in mind, above all, that Python 3 is **the** current python branch.

If you are just starting with python, or intend on starting a new project, it is recommended that you do so with Python 3.